# Display content on Website after person clicks LIKE

Tags: jquery, facebook-like

I would like to hide a portion on my website until the reader LIKES my site.

I understand this can be done using FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create' but I can not get it to work. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Can you please post the code plus any errors that you current experience ....

Comment: we **would** like to help you, but we need some more information - code samples, errors, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Using the Facebook SDK you can do this:

```
<?php
require 'src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
 'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
try {
    $likes = $facebook->api("/me/likes/YOUR PAGE ID");
    if( !empty($likes['data']) )
    {
        ?>
        <p>Your fan-only content</p>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
    <p>Content for non-fans (if any)</p>
        <?php
    }
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
    }
}

if ($user) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} 
else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'user_likes'
));
}
?>
```

You need to create an app on Facebook though and give it the correct parameters, which is a task in itself to get working!

Comment: This will not help our friend @Veronika because they are looking for a way to change content **after** the `like` event - as opposed to a pre-condition test that you gave here.  Your solution would require a page refresh after the `like` action.

Comment: AHA..I need to create an app. And the above looks like it is for a facebook page rather then a website.

Comment: Yes, an app is needed for this code to work. Also, this code will work either on a custom tab for your page OR on your own website. If you have a like button already on your page and you want to show content immediately after it's clicked then more work would be required but if the user has already liked your facebook page then visits your site then this should definitley work.

Comment: Is there a way to do this Lix? What I want to do seems simple on the face of it, but I've been struggling for days. All I want is for the reader to click LIKE on our website, and then be shown content that was hidden.

Comment: The above code **would** work on a facebook page and on a website - however it would require a refresh after the like action.

Comment: @Lix, I understand your comment and it's true but from what I can tell it wasn't really specified if it should be what I have posted or as you say, a like button on the webpage itself.

Comment: I'm not sure if jQuery could be used to target the like button and for that click function to trigger the new content, that's something I've not done before.

Comment: See the other answers - this **is** possible.  With regard to the question : "hide a portion on my website **until** the reader LIKES my site" - My understanding is the need for an action as a result of the like event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to capture a like event :

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);
```

As you can see it uses the `FB` object which is created when initialising the [Facebook JS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) so you **will** have to create a facebook app for this.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example :

```
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <fb:like send="false" layout="button_count" width="100" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
        <div id="hidden_content" style="display:none;">...</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
              window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
                });

                // Additional initialization code here
                   FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function() { 
                      $('#hidden_content').show();
                  });
             };

          // Load the SDK Asynchronously
          (function(d){
             var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
             js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
             js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
             d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
           }(document));
        </script>
```

Comment: would this even work? can you initiate the JS SDK with out all the parameters? no APP_ID?  I think not... But... if i am wrong - please... dont keep it to yourself ;)

Comment: Yes you can :)
The need for a AppId is restricted to some advanced functions (sending requests by example ...)

Comment: You could be right, however I dont think there is a need to test facebooks documentation : "You will need an app ID to initialize the SDK, which you can obtain from the Developer App." Taken from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).

Comment: Of course ... facebook documentation is so complete and exhaustive ...

As I told before : it works. To subscribe to the edge.create event there is no need to obtain an appId. Of course, having one would be "cleaner" but as there is only one thing needed here (catch edge.create event), i gave the easiest answer possible.

Comment: You could be right - but implementing code that goes against the documentation is generally not a good idea.  It might work now - but when/if it stops working - only the programmer will be responsible.